# Making confirmation webpage for form informaton confirmation

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
function confirm(){
var firstname = getElementById("fname").value;
var lastname = getElementById("lname").value;
var streetaddress = getElementById("streetaddress").value;
var currentstate = getElementById("currentstate").value;
var phone = getElementById("phone").value;
var email = getElementById("email").value;
// var gender = getElementById("gender").value;
var programmingexp = getElementById("programmingexp").value;
var proglang = getElementById("proglang").value;
// var yearofstudy = getElementById("yearofstudy").value;
// var personalinfo = getElementById("personalinfo").value;

localStorage.setItem("firstname", firstname);
localStorage.setItem("lastname", lastname);
localStorage.setItem("streetaddress", streetaddress);
localStorage.setItem("currentstate", currentstate);
localStorage.setItem("phone", phone);
localStorage.setItem("email", email);
// localStorage.setItem("gender", gender);
localStorage.setItem("programmingexp", programmingexp);
localStorage.setItem("proglang", proglang);
// localStorage.setItem("yearsofstudy", yearsofstudy);
// localStorage.setItem("personalinfo", personalinfo);

var confirmW = window.open("confirm.html");

return confirmW;
}

function testOpen() {
    window.open("confirm.html");
}
```

I have set both functions to invoke, but only the testOpen() function is opening up the second HTML page. Is there anything that I need to fix in confirm() for the webpage to at least open? Below is the HTML page where the function is being used.

```
<!-- Activity-4 Creating register.html file
register.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html><!-- Doctype declaration -->
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"><!-- meta declaration -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>UNCP-ACM Student Chapter</title> <!-- title declaration -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="theme.css">
    
    <script src="register.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>ACM Student Chapter of UNCP</h1>
    <h2>APPLICATION FORM</h2>
    <form name="myform" onsubmit="return confirm();">
    <fieldset class="grid-container">
        <legend>Personal Information</legend>
        <label class="lname" for="lname">Last Name:</label>
        <input class="lname" type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
        <label class="fname" for="fname">First Name:</label>
        <input class="fname" type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
        
        <label class="streetaddress" for="streetaddress">Street Address:</label>
        <input class="streetaddress" type="text" id="streetaddress" name="streetaddress">
        
        <label class="currentstate" for="currentstate">Current State:</label>
        <select class="currentstate" id="currentstate">
            <option value="Florida">Florida</option>
            <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
            <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
            <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
            <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
        </select><br>
        
        <label class="phone" for="phone">Enter your phone number:</label>
        <input class="phone" type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" placeholder="###-###-####">
        <label class="email" for="email">Email:</label>
        <input class="email" type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="name@uncp.edu"><br>
        
        <p class="gender">Gender:</p>
        <div class="gender" id="gender">
            <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender"><label for="male">Male</label>
            <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender"><label for="female">Female</label>
        </div>
        
        <label class="programmingexp" for="programmingexp">Years of programming experience:</label>
        
        <div class="slider"> 
            <label>0</label>
            <input type="range" min="0" max="20" value="10" id="programmingexp">
            <label>20</label>
        </div>
        
        <label class="proglang" for="proglang">Select all the programming languages that you know (hold ctrl or shift key to select multiple entries)</label>
        <select class="proglang" name="proglang" id="proglang" multiple>
            <option value="c++">C++</option>
            <option value="java">Java</option>
            <option value="python">Python</option>
            <option value="c#">C#</option>
        </select>
        </fieldset>
        <br>
        
        <fieldset id="yearofstudy">
        <legend>Year of study</legend>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="">Freshman
        </label>
        
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="">Sophomore
        </label>
        
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="">Junior
        </label>
        
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="">Senior
        </label>
        </fieldset>
        
        
        <br>
        <label for="personalinfo">Write something about you....</label><br><br>
        <textarea id="personalinfo" name="personalinfo" rows="8" cols="50"></textarea>
        
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>  
</html>
```

The code that is provided above is from an assignment for a class. The professor gave us a bit of code for the confirm function and wanted us to fill the rest in. I have filled the rest in but I cannot get the confirm.html page to open. So to test it I made the testOpen() function. This is our first assignment actually using JS and I couldn't find anything in the book to help me out. I have also looked on the internet and cannot find anything that is all that helpful for what I am trying to do.

Comment: Please elaborate what you are expecting

Comment: The function is supposed to store data from a form in local storage and then open a confirmation page that will allow them to view the information that the user inputted. But for whatever reason, the confirm() function will not open the confirmation page.

Comment: Are you using a `form` tag?

Comment: Yes, I am using a form tag. I will edit the post to include the HTML.

Comment: I have included the HTML page the function is being invoked in.

Answer (score 0):

You can rather use `action` attribute in the `form` tag which will URL Encode the form values and pass it on to the action page as query parameter. You can then use `URLSearchParams` to get the values without any hassle.

eg: `<form action="something.html">` then you can do something like

```
const data = new URLSearchParams(location.search),
      fname = data.get('fname'),
      lname = data.get('lname')
      ...
```

The error you are getting is because you are returning the function `confirm()` on submit. You were supposed to call the function not return it. So changing it to `onsubmit="confirm()"` should fix your issue